# navigation in php and html and javascript hover effects too

Tags: php, javascript, html, dynamic, hover

i have a website and i am using php to navigate and i am trying to use a single web page, i also have a contact page that slides up from the bottom

in the hrefs is something like href="?id=contactme" and then i use a switch() function to navigate the pages

but when i goto the Contact page and then try to navigate away from it, it adds whatever href to that current one like ...com/?id=contactme?

now i am wondering should i be using absolute links in these hrefs or is that always the recommendation

also while testing all this on a test server on my computer would mean changing back the links to the localhost,

any other help or suggestions would be great

also one other question on php can i use hover links or elements with php where the screen or another div changes or do i have to use javascript?

Answer (score 1):

If all of your pages are going through a boot-strap (ie index.php) then change you href to

```
<a href="index.php?id=contactme">Contact Us</a>
```

For the second part of your question, you will have to use javascript. Look into jquery as it makes some tasks a lot easier.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a front controller pattern like that (i.e. one script file which controls display of all pages).  I personally think you are better off utilizing the URL rewrite functionality of your web server of choice (for example mod_rewrite for Apache), to produce clean URL's that all point to the single controller file.  So for example, you could have URL's for the end user like:

```
www.domain.com/contactme
www.domain.com/anotherpage
www.domain.com/yetanotherpage
```

These could all be directed by the server to something like:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?page=contactme
www.domain.com/index.php?page=anotherpage
www.domain.com/index.php?page=yetanotherpage
```

with the browser still showing the original "clean" URL in it's address bar.  In other words, the fact that the webserver directs requests to index.php is hidden from the end user.  Your links within your HTML would also use these "clean" URL's as well, making it to where you don't have to worry about passing the actual parameters yourself.

An example `.htaccess` file that you could use on Apache might look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This would direct all incoming requests that are not for an actual file or directory name to your `index.php` front controller.

So your HTML would simply be like this:

```
<a href="/contactme">Text</a>
```

In regards to styling elements on hover, you can use CSS `:hover` pseudo-class for a lot of basic hover styling, however for most modern web applications, you will probably end up using a combination of CSS and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the Browser for adding the current URL to your query you can either use relative paths like

```
<a href="index.php?id=contactme">
```

or absolue paths like

```
<a href="/index.php?id=contactme">
```

the absolute path is equal to

```
<a href="http://localhost/index.php?id=contactme">
or
<a href="http://mydomain.com/index.php?id=contactme">
```

Comment: You're "absolute" path is a *relative* link to the document root.